# Escape special characters/Symbols in XML?

Tags: java, xml, set, character

while creating a XML using a table in my DB , i got many special characters like registered trademark, trademark, degree, different punctuation, etc (these are present in symbol form , hexadecimal, name code , number code  )... .  some other words like   , °, ...

Also some characters are shown as x99,xEA, etc in my XML.

Is there a library/ API to handle all these while creating XML using JAVA Code.
I am using "UTF-8" character encoding for my XML.

Also i cann't clean my DB to have consistent data since it's production data.

Comment: You should just provide the data to an XML API, and it will escape and unescape as required.

Comment: StringUtils.escapeXml()

Answer (score 0):

A potential option is to enclose your data in [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect) tags, which marks the data as character data that may include markup, but should not be processed as such.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [free command line tool](http://hll.nu/purchase/GetFreeXPL.htm) for transforming files with special characters in text to valid XML. It also assures that the file encoding matches what is specified in the declaration.

There is also a Java developer suite that allows you to use the parser to parse such files (called XPL) as an alternative to XML or a pre-process into XML. It uses a StAX-like process called StAX-PL.